# How to Retrieve Current balance of the bank Account in Netsuite

Tags: web-services, netsuite

I need to retrieve the current balance of bank Account in Netsuite using SuiteTalk(Netsuite Webservise).In suite talk API there is no field/parameter to refer the balance of account.But There is UI field Balance which shows the current balance of the account.Any help/suggestions on this is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If there is no field/parameter in the API referencing that UI field, it is most likely that the field is not supported by the API.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not intuitive, but it is possible to pull this data using the API. Here's an example using the [netsuite ruby bindings](https://github.com/netsweet/netsuite).

```
  def balance_for_account(ns_account)
    search = NetSuite::Records::Account.search(
      criteria: {
        basic: [
          {
            field: 'internalIdNumber',
            operator: 'equalTo',
            value: ns_account.internal_id
          }
        ]
      },

      columns: {
        'listAcct:basic' => {
          'platformCommon:internalId/' => {},
          'platformCommon:balance' => {}
        }
      }
    )

    search.results.first.attributes[:balance].to_f
  end
```